# How to convert with boost:asio:ip:address IPV6 to IPV4

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I write a litte program with boost::asio to convert ipv6 in ipv4, it compiles well but if I run my program I got:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::bad_cast> >'
  what():  std::bad_cast
Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)`

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio/ip/address.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

int main(){
    address myIP = address::from_string("fe80::c87f:db87:787b:a7c4");
    address_v6 myIP6 = myIP.to_v6();
    address_v4 myIP4 = myIP.to_v4();
    cout << myIP4.to_string() <<endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: There are more ipv6 addresses than ipv4. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: An ipv6 address simply won't fit in an ipv4 address - that's basically why the newer standard exists! What output could this program reasonably give?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. A `boost::asio::ip::address` is *either* an IPv6 address, *or* an IPv4 address. It is **not both** at once.

It is simply not meaningful to talk about "convert IPv6 to IPv4". The closest thing would to be constructing a table of "known addresses for a particular host" and looking within that for an address of a different kind to the one you have.